# Actual image not saving to directory

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

1. username input will create a directory if username input john it will create john
2. the image will be uploaded to webroot\img\users\john\uploaded1.jpg

users table had destination field.

It will insert in the database the correct destination path   D:\xampp\htdocs\sample\webroot\img\users\john\uploaded1.jpg

but the uploaded1.jpg is not added and the warning below cannot moved file

Warning (2): move_uploaded_file(D:\xampp\htdocs\sample\webroot\img\users\james\uploaded1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 584]
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [https://secure.php.net/function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'D:\xampp-for-cakephp3\tmp\php3FD6.tmp' to 'D:\xampp\htdocs\sample\webroot\img\james\uploaded1.jpg' [APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 584]

```
<?php

public function register()
{       
      $user = $this->Users->newEntity();

      $value = $this->request->getData('username');  // holds the username input

      if($this->request->is('post')) {

            $image_name        = $this->request->data['profile_pic']['name'];
            $image_tmp         = $this->request->data['profile_pic']['tmp_name'];


            $destination       = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$value.DS.$image_name;

            //debug($destination);exit;

              move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $destination);
              $this->request->data['profile_pic'] = $image_name;
              $this->request->data['destination'] = $destination;


             $user= $this->Users->patchEntity($user,$this->request->getData());
             if($this->Users->save($user)) {

                 $dir = new Folder();

                 $path_data = $dir->create(WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$value,true,0777); 

                 $this->Flash->success(__('User profile successfuly  updated.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
          } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        }

        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    } 
?>
```

Comment: did you save an imposter as opposed to the actual one?  Sorry I had to ask.

Comment: what you mean tmp ?

Comment: It was a joke, sorry, anyway, does this folder exist and is it writable `img\james`  I don't use Cake, but it could very easily be a file permission issue, or at least that is my go-to thought.  It's pretty much saying that right here `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` aka make sure you didnt use root to create it, I actually did something like this today on a wordpress site... lol

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the folder doesn't exist, so to overcome this error you have to create the folder first using the USER INPUT.

Consider your example, user input is John

```
$value = $this->request->getData('username');    //User input
$image_name = $this->request->data['profile_pic']['name'];
$image_tmp = $this->request->data['profile_pic']['tmp_name'];


$user_input_folder = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$value.DS;
$destination = $user_input_folder.$image_name;

if (!file_exists($user_input_folder)) {   //Checks file or folder exist or not


    if(mkdir($filePath, 0777, true)){
         $oldMask = umask(0);
         chmod($filePath, 0777);
         umask($oldMask);

         //Then do your file upload
         echo $destination;
         var_dump(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $destination));die;
     } else {
           pr("User input contains at least one illegal character, so can't create folder.");die;
     }
}
```

Comment: i try to copy your program code but It does not to my self, where should I put your code below of this  if($this->request->is('post')) {  your code..... }  or  below of this one      if($this->Users->save($user)) { your code..... }

Comment: actually my code  will create a directory but the actual image will not upload to that folder... but it will saved to database which have a field,, destination

Comment: if($this->request->is('post')) { your code..... } use this and let me know the return of *move_uploaded_file*, I have updated the code so that you can see the return.

Comment: it will print the exact directory with the exact image.. but does not insert in the database

Comment: i try to  uncomment the var_dump and die; but cant do it

Comment: "it will print the exact directory with the exact image" :- var_dump() will not give the exact image, it will return you true or false, you have to debug

Comment: updated error    
    
    
  
 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/567ab21b46e23a49aa9c3a43f729f55e

Comment: I have no idea about your table structure(column), but the errors are because of  "$this->request->getData()", it contains the file array and you have to use only the USER FILE NAME instead of the file array.

Comment: Im just added     $this->request->data['destination'] = $destination;/// to store to destination field 
  before the move_uploaded file and turn off to FALSE but is their a way to fixed this one  
 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f9f773d40f373845ec1ee16696206687